# Easy exponential equation but…

Tags: exponential-function

$$\left(\sqrt{5+2\sqrt6}\right)^x-\left(\sqrt{5-2\sqrt6}\right)^x=96$$
I was trying to use that $$(5+2\sqrt6)(5-2\sqrt6)=1$$ but I end up with $$t^2-98t+1=0$$ which has some ugly solutions and I think I should have some nice ones there. Thx

Comment: It should be $t^2-96t-1=0.$

Comment: Well, could be.. stil $\Delta$ is not a perfect square

Comment: Lol, I m stupid..I think I have found the mistake

Comment: But we can end it.$

Answer (score 1):

It should be $t^2-96t-1=0,$ which gives
$$t=48+\sqrt{2305}$$ and
$$x=\log_{\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{6}}}(48+\sqrt{2305})$$ or
$$x=\log_{\sqrt2+\sqrt3}(48+\sqrt{2305})$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{6}}\right)^x - \left(\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{6}}\right)^x = 96$$
Take natural log of both sides
$$\ln \left[ \left(\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{6}}\right)^x - \left(\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{6}}\right)^x \right]= \ln96$$
Use the $\ln(a+b) = \ln(a) + \ln(1+b/a)$ property
$$\ln \left(\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{6}}\right)^x + \ln \left(1-\dfrac{\left(\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{6}}\right)^x}{\left(\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{6}}\right)^x}\right)=\ln96$$
Take out the $x$ from the log
$$x \left[\ln\left(\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{6}}\right)\right] + x\left[\ln\left(1-\dfrac{\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{6}}}{\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{6}}}\right)\right] =\ln96$$
Factor the $x$ and isolate it
$$x=\dfrac {\ln96} {\ln\left(\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{6}}\right) + \ln\left(1-\dfrac{\sqrt{5-2\sqrt{6}}}{\sqrt{5+2\sqrt{6}}}\right)}$$
The rest is just computation

Comment: This might not be right as in wofram alpha the solution is complex